# Python adding a number sequence in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

There is a list of dictionary.

```
[{'skillid': 1, 'QueText': u'xxxx, 'Feedback':u'xxxx} , {'skillid': 1, 'QueTextt': u'xxx, 'Feedback': u'xxx}, {'skillid': .....}]
```

How to insert a new key with the value in sequence?  (key value is 'QueNo' and the value is in sequence according to the sequence)

Required output:

```
[{'skillid':1, 'QueText': u'xxx, 'QueNo': 1, 'Feedback': u'xxx},
{'skillid':1, 'QueText': u'xxx, 'QueNo': 2, 'Feedback': u'xxx},
{ ..............................'QueNo':3,  .................}]
```

Comment: Dictionaries have no order by design. List have order and index but dictionaries use keys for setting/getting values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a test and seems good, codes like this:

```
seq=[{'skillid': 1, 'QueText': u'quetext', 'Feedback':u'feedback'} , {'skillid': 1, 'QueText': u'quetext', 'Feedback':u'feedback'},{'skillid': 1, 'QueText': u'quetext', 'Feedback': u'feedback'} ]
# print seq
count=1
for subseq in seq:
    subseq.setdefault('QueNo',count)
    count+=1
    print subseq
```

And dictionary will be ordered print like this:

```
{'Feedback': u'feedback', 'QueNo': 1, 'QueText': u'quetext', 'skillid': 1}
{'Feedback': u'feedback', 'QueNo': 2, 'QueText': u'quetext', 'skillid': 1}
{'Feedback': u'feedback', 'QueNo': 3, 'QueText': u'quetext', 'skillid': 1}
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion Shonminh.  It worked perfectly.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can `enumerate` your list and add the `QueNo` key:

```
for i, d in enumerate(l, 1):
  d['QueNo'] = i
```